# Does Ansible check relative vars files when using -m with a global inventory?

Tags: ansible

I created a file,

```
./group_vars/all
```

which has a simple line

```
---
ansible_user: centos
```

My inventory filemy `/etc/ansible/inventory` has

```
[centos]
10.1.38.15
```

However, when I use `ansible -m ping` I see that it's trying to connect with my regular user.

```
~/cp/ansible$ ansible -vvv centos -m ping
.... stuff
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ecarroll@10.1.38.15: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
    "unreachable": true
```

You can see it's trying to connect with `ecarroll@` and not `centos@`. Does Ansible `-m` work with `./group_vars/` if I'm using a global inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation (my emphasis):](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

> You can also add `group_vars/` and `host_vars/` directories to your playbook directory. The `ansible-playbook` command looks for these directories in the current working directory by default. Other Ansible commands (for example, `ansible`, `ansible-console`, etc.) **will only look for `group_vars/` and `host_vars/` in the inventory directory.** If you want other commands to load group and host variables from a playbook directory, you must provide the `--playbook-dir` option on the command line. If you load inventory files from both the playbook directory and the inventory directory, variables in the playbook directory will override variables set in the inventory directory.

So you'll have to provide those vars to the command itself, you can do that with

```
ansible -m setup 10.1.38.15 -e ansible_user=centos
```

or,

```
ansible -u centos -m setup 10.1.38.15
```

Comment: can you confirm your group_vars/all is not in etc? ie, are you running this from an arbitrary directory?

Comment: Yes, it is from the current working directory from where I execute the ansible command. This was just intended as a POC.

Comment: is your hosts file also local?

Comment: Yes. The hosts file is also local, as specified with `-i hosts` it also resides in the current working directory.

Comment: can you delete the local hosts file, and add the hosts to the global hosts file and try it again.

Comment: Just did (no need to delete the file though as Ansible defaults there without the `-i` switch), and that indeed does *not* work. You must place the `group_vars` file in the inventory directory.

Comment: well..that's not intuitive moving a host into a global inventory file shouldn't require restructuring the app.

Comment: I think we should nuke the rest of this answer, except that quote which is priceless.

Comment: Looks like this is a common, if unexpected, behavior. https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/89 
Personally, I always use `remote_user` because the var name just makes more sense to me. If my user account is executing `ansible` on my control machine, isn't my user account the "ansible user", regardless of what connectivity options I specify in config ini's or cli parameters? *Just my $0.02.*